# DEP0018 error when installing a package

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install a package for my project in IONIC v1 and I am getting this error:

[image]

when executing this command:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\tin_app>cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps@2.3.1 \ --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="xxxx"
```

Why does this happen and what can I do to solve it? I would appreciate it if you would explain me well, I am quite new in this topic and I can not find a solution. please have me patience I am new in this world.
thank you.

Comment: can you try ionic plugin add plugin-name if its v1?

Comment: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps@2.3.1 \ --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="xxxx"` using IONIC v1

Comment: ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps@2.3.1 \ --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="xxxx. Try this

Comment: @SunilRawat not works...it works for me, I just added --save seems to work now ... I see the same error, but at least the plugin already works ..

Comment: ok great. atleast its working